# Batch for each to copy each specific file from its directory to is own subdirectory

Tags: batch-file

i have a directoy structure thus

```
C:folder\
        \davis\Myfiles\saved
        \brown\Myfiles\saved
        \smith\Myfiles\saved
        \jones\Myfiles\saved
```

what i want to achive is this

```
for each directory called 'Myfiles'
   IF NOT Exists 'Myfiles\*doc.rtf'
      copy files caled 'Myfiles\*doc.txt' to the subdirectory 'Myfiles\saved'
      move files called 'Myfiles\*doc.txt' to 'somewhereElse'
```

But how do i do this with a batch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read `HELP FOR` and try this code that may help you get started...

```
for /r /d %%a in (*) do (
 if /i %%~na==myfiles (
    pushd %%a
    for %%b in (*doc.txt) do (
     if not exist %%~nb.rtf (
       echo copy %%b saved
       echo move %%b \somehwereelse
     )
    )
    popd
  )
)
```